# Is there a way to make a css property reactive with vuejs @scroll?

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm making a vuejs component in my project, and i need to create a zoom with scroll, in a div (like googlemaps).

```
<div @scroll="scroll">
    <Plotly :data="info" :layout="layout" :display-mode-bar="false"></Plotly>
</div>

<style>
  div {
  transform: scale(property1);
  }
<\style>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        scroll(event) {
        },
    },
    created() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll);
    },
    destroyed() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scroll);
    }
}
</script>
```

How can i make a method that make the "property1" reactive? Or there is another way to zoom with scroll only the div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can bind a dynamic style object to your `div` which includes the `transform` property with a dynamic value (see [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) for deeper explanation):

```html
<div @scroll="scroll" :style="{ transform : `scale(${property1})`}">
      <Plotly :data="info" :layout="layout" :display-mode-bar="false"></Plotly>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
   ...
   data() {
     return {
        property1: defaultValue
     }
   },
   methods : {
      scroll(e){
         // e is the event emitted from the scroll listener
         this.property1 = someValue
      }
   }
})
```

You can also add some modifiers in the template as shown in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) to reduce the method code (here we could be preventing the page from scrolling whenever the user will be scrolling while hovering this specific element):

```html
<div @scroll.self.stop="scroll" :style="{ transform : `scale(${property1})`}">
      <Plotly :data="info" :layout="layout" :display-mode-bar="false"></Plotly>
</div>
```